# Почему папка в которой продакшн версия пуст

Tags: javascript, gulp

1. В папке app находится рабочая версия проекта. В папке dist должна лежать продакшн версия проекта. Я не совсем понимаю, почему она пустая. Галп ведь вроде бы должен компилировать туда все файлы.
2. Не работает плагин gulp-rigger. Браузер просто выводит строку //=html_includes/footer.html  Как его настроить?
   Объясните пожалуйста.

gulpfile.js

```js
var gulp    = require('gulp'),
 sass    = require('gulp-sass'),
 rigger    = require('gulp-rigger'),
 browserSync  = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
 return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.scss')
 .pipe(sass())
 .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
 .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function(){
 browserSync({
  server: {
   baseDir: 'app'
  },
  notify: false
 })
});

gulp.task('html', function(){
  return gulp.src('app/html_includes/*.html')
  .pipe(rigger())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('app/'))
  .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync', 'sass'], function(){
 gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
 gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload);
 gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
});
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "project1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.5",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-rigger": "^0.5.8",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `dist` - от слова `distributive`, что на простом языке означает завершенное ПО, к коему можно отнести библиотеку, фраймворк. То есть использовать директорию с названием `dist` стоит в том случае если Вы пишите библиотеку.
- `dest` - от слова `destination`, что можно интерпретировать как **место назначения**. Использовать стоит тогда, когда Вы собираете приложение.

А конкретно по вопросу, это все банально просто, Вы сами указали `gulp.dest` (место куда складывать) в директорию `app`. Исправьте это и проект будет компилироваться в нужное место.

Comment: По второму вопросу могу сказать следующие.. Есть множество причин. Если Вы видите в скомпилированном виде правильный `html` файл, то возможно browserSync обновляет страницу раньше чем происходит компиляция.